# How do I disable the Alt - Tab switcher?

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I would like to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (or all of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ combinations) on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tried to disable at *System preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts*, but this method doesn't seem to be working.
Later I tried to activate an own shortcut for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (like an overwriting attempt), without any success...

Is there a way to disable this with or without compiz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager, find the Ubuntu unity plugin, Switcher tab, Set `Key to start switcher` to `disabled`

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: @gonzobrains In the remote case you still need it, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab']"` (tested on Ubuntu 17.10). The default settings bind both `Alt` and `Super`, these commands remove the bindings with the `Alt` key and leave only those with `Super`.

Comment: Arch, please make that an answer. I couldn't get the 'correct answer' to work for me, however yours did