# What is this window selector popup and how do I disable it?

Tags: 16.04

This popup only seems to show up randomly when I do some sort of track pad movement. I have never been able to figure out what I have to do to make it show up on command, it is always when I don't want it. Whenever it does show up it's like a roulette of windows; you never know if it will keep your current window open or close a random one and open a different one. It's absolutely abysmal. I admit, I am extremely frustrated at it and I just want to know how to disable it.
Here is a picture of it I managed to snag during one of the times it randomly showed up:
[image: The window box in the center]

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

This is the windows switcher usually accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key combination. To turn off the keyboard method this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/212164/how-do-i-disable-the-alt-tab-switcher?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) states:

> Install CompizConfig Settings Manager, find the Ubuntu unity plugin,
>   Switcher tab, Set `Key to start switcher` to `disabled`

My touchpad doesn't invoke the windows switcher so I cannot test this on my system.

If this method doesn't work another method is editing Unity source and recompiling: [How can I disable arbitrary default multitouch gestures in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57586/how-can-i-disable-arbitrary-default-multitouch-gestures-in-unity)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to disable the touch gesture. The keybinding itself can be managed in the keyboard shortcuts settings, without using ccsm.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find a possible solution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/461481/help-to-disable-the-multi-touch-gestures-in-14-04 I ran synclient ClickFinger3=2 which disabled it from showing up when you tap 3 fingers (which I guess is what it was detecting on accident?). I think this should cover the bulk of my issues.